# Troubleshoot a specific mysql error on import database

Tags: mysql

I have run into an error in trying to import a mysql dump:

```
[ERROR in query 369] Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Is there a simple way to find which query this is referring to so I can diagnose it? Otherwise I need to find which is the 369th query and then investigate that and whether I have an error in the index statement or if it's a version issue. What would be the best way to go about finding which query this is referring to?

Comment: You can just open the dump file in a text editor, can't you?

Comment: @BillKarwin of course but then wouldn't I have to count out the 268 queries? Each query doesn't have its own line and there are comments as well...

Comment: In vim: `368/;<enter>` searches for `;` 368 times. There's probably an equivalent in emacs, I never took the time to learn emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from an index creation into an InnoDB-table which has a limit of 767 bytes per index. So, you have an index on a column / columns with combined length greater than 767 bytes.

If you use utf8mb4, a single column with width > 191 (4×191) characters will cause this. Most common cause would be an index on a varchar(255) column.

Comment: I see. What about actually finding the query though. Is there a way to find which query it refers to though?

Comment: Check the `CREATE TABLE` statements / index creation statements. If you changed to `utf8mb4` (4-bytes) in your database, you can also use uft8 instead (3 bytes).

Comment: Remove the indexe from the table before you import. After the import query the lenght of each field like **select LENGTH(field1),LENGTH(field3),LENGTH(field3), LENGTH(field1) + LENGTH(field3) + LENGTH(field3) as totallength from yourtable order by totallength DESC** to see which row have the longest index. you can also set the key length smaler when you recreate the index